# Convert columns to binary (0 or 1) inplace using conditions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert column values to 0 or 1s. If the column value is >0 then it should be 1 otherwise if it is <=0 then it should be 0. I have over 100 columns.
Example df is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                     "col1": [0, 0, 2, 0, 7], 
                     "col2": [121, 9, 22, 3, 7], 
                     "col3": [181, 0, 2, 3, 0]})
```

I can achieve the answer using the threshold for 1 column at a time, but I have 100s of columns.

```
threshold = 0
df['col1'] = df['col1'].gt(threshold).astype(int)
```

Answer should be:

```
answerdf = pd.DataFrame({
                     "col1": [0, 0, 1, 0, 1], 
                     "col2": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
                     "col3": [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]})
```

Comment: `df = df.gt(threshold).astype(int)`?

Comment: It worked. Thanks! That was a bad question.